# fatal error: 'boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp' file not found

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile the think-cell-library according to their documentation. However I am getting fatal error: 'boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp' file not found when I try to compile it with > gcc -std=c++2a -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost@1.76/1.76.0_4 range.example.cpp
I installed the boost library with homebrew and check whether it is installed. I got stuck so I need help. Also here is the repository of think-cell: https://github.com/think-cell/think-cell-library

I tried to change the version of boost that think-cell noticed that they are tested it with 1.75 but I can only download 1.76 so that I tried it with 1.76 and latest version of boost but still getting fatal error: 'boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp' file not found error.

Comment: Solved it with > g++ -std=c++2a -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost@1.76/1.76.0_4/include -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost@1.76/1.76.0_4 range.example.cpp

Comment: That header was [added to boost in 2002](https://github.com/boostorg/preprocessor/blob/54bdb3861938ef68d1e598b046d83cc1db1fbf3f/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp) and is still there now so the boost version is unlikely to be related. At a guess your compilation simply isn't finding boost at all

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

> g++ -std=c++2a -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost@1.76/1.76.0_4/include -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost@1.76/1.76.0_4 range.example.cpp
> command and recieved out file.